# Appengine datstore keyname reserved keywords

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I got the following error message telling me that `__K__` cannot be used as datastore entity keyname. 
Is there a list of reserved keyname that I can follow?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtooadex2/test:v1.372093270511118603/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 401, in handle
    tstate.input_reader, shard_state, tstate, ctx)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtooadex2/test:v1.372093270511118603/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 465, in process_inputs
    entity, input_reader, ctx, tstate):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtooadex2/test:v1.372093270511118603/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 502, in process_data
    result = handler(data)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~tagtooadex2/test:v1.372093270511118603/main.py", line 124, in mapper
    obj.put()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3232, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 748, in put
    key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 280, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 454, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1675, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1236, in check_rpc_success
    raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
BadRequestError: The key.key.path.element.name "__K__" is reserved.
```

Comment: I seem to recall reading somewhere the reserved words are prefixed __ to avoid exactly this. So perhaps pick a different prefix would be easiest as even if you get your list of reserved words then it might change and stop your app working at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Kinds_and_identifiers , "All kind names that begin with two underscores (__) are reserved and may not be used."